# In Java 1.7 I have error : java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission"

Tags: java, linux

This is a complete error when I am running applet and try to connect to another server

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "172.16.0.74:21" "connect,resolve")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:574)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:958)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:918)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1013)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:999)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:292)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
        at connectnewgene.init(connectnewgene.java:37)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:435)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the JVM security context won't allow you to do that by default, on purpose

Comment: Applets are not supposed to be able to connect to anywhere but the server they were downloaded from, unless you grant them additional permissions. This was one of their main selling points.